# How can you tell if a stream extraction to a variable failed?

Tags: c++

I am extracting data from a string stream into a `string` and a `double`:

```
std::string word;
double num;
std::istringstream stream("hello x");

stream >> word >> num;

std::cout << word;
std::cout << num;
```

Is it possible to tell if the second token, `"x"` was successfully parsed into an `int`?

In this case, it would obviously not, and the value of x is `0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The extraction operator (>>) will return true or false on whether the extraction was successful.

```
if (stream >> num)
  cout << "success\n";
else
  cout << "failed\n";
```

In addition, you will likely see the failbit set on the `istringstream` object

```
if (stream.fail())
  cout << "failbit is set\n";
```

Comment: The extraction operator returns a reference to the stream (not a boolean). The stream is put into a fail state on failure, and the stream has an implicit conversion to boolean that checks the relevant failure bit.

Comment: That's really handy to know.  Thanks for the quick answer, @nkryptic! And I appreciate your clarification @MattMcNabb.